# Azure Search - Difference between Upload & MergeOrUpload

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

What is the difference between the 2 methods Upload versus MergeOrUpload in Azure Search.

They both do exactly the same thing. i.e. they both will upload a document if it does not exist and replace the document if it already does exist.

Is there any performance differences that could be gained due to the fact that the two methods may be using different underlying strategies.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Upload` creates a new document or **replaces** the **entire** original document. 
In contrast, `MergeOrUpload` creates a new document or **merges** the input document with the existing document, making it possible, for example, to change only specific fields or add new fields without changing the rest of the document. 
See [Add, Update or Delete documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Merge Or Upload still does not make sense to me. If you know a document exists then you use Merge. If you don't then you use this method which means you are not sure if a document exists or not. This in turn means that you have to supply ALL fields (not just a portion) which defeats the objective of the Merge part.

Comment: Imagine you have two processes that both add documents into a search index without coordinating with each other. Each does not know whether a document exists, and each wishes to avoid overwriting the other's data. This is the prototypical use case for `mergeOrUpload`.